# How to make user log on only once?

Tags: c#, asp.net-membership

We are using ASP membership database to manage our websites security, and each website corresponding to one membership role. I made a portal site to list all the hyperlinks to these project websites (all the user within any role can log on to this portal site), and in the webconfig file, I list all the roles for every project website:

```
<authorization>      
      <allow roles="Administrators,ProjectId1_Member,ProjectId10_Member,ProjectId11_Member,ProjectId12_Member,ProjectId13_Member,ProjectId14_Member,ProjectId15_Member,ProjectId16_Member,ProjectId17_Member,ProjectId18_Member,ProjectId19_Member,ProjectId2_Member,ProjectId21_Member,ProjectId22_Member,ProjectId23_Member,ProjectId24_Member,ProjectId25_Member, "/>
      <deny users="*"/>
 </authorization>
```

But it works for the user to log on to the Portal site. But if the user click the hyperlink to navigate to a particular project website, the user will be navigated to the login page again. Is there a way that I can avoid this double login happens?

Thanks,

Wei

Comment: Your forms authentication cookies are not shared between websites, most probably.

Comment: How are the sites named - are they `www.site1.com`, `www.site2.com`, or `site1.company.com`, `site2.company.com` or something else?

Comment: To Tisho: our sites name are companySite/projectA/index.aspx ,  companySite/projectB/index.aspx.

To Wiktor: how should I share authentication cookies among websites?

Thanks, you guys!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure path is / and enable cross-path redirects

```
 <authentication mode="Windows">
 <forms 
    name=".ASPXAUTH" 
    loginUrl="login.aspx" 
    defaultUrl="default.aspx" 
    protection="All" 
    timeout="30" 
    path="/" 
    requireSSL="false" 
    slidingExpiration="true" 
    cookieless="UseDeviceProfile" 
    domain="companySite" 
    enableCrossAppRedirects="true">
    <credentials passwordFormat="SHA1" />
 </forms>
 <passport redirectUrl="internal" />
 </authentication>
```

Comment: Thanks, Darek. Do I need to put this code into every site's Web.config? Also, do I need to change any parameter besides "domain"?

Comment: Technically the domain can stay empty, filling it out makes the cookie more secure. Yes, every web.config needs to have the authentication node similar. Meaning the redirects can be different, the timeouts can be different, but the rest, especially path, passwordFormat and cookieLess, need to be the same.